# How to make React Native content appear under camera on Android?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

please forgive me if this is something basic, I'm currently learning React Native but am stuck at this point.

So I know that SafeAreaView cannot be used for Android devices so following a YouTube tutorial I have added this line to the styles:

`paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,`

The problem I'm facing is while this works and the content is now under the status bar, the punch hole from the camera is covering it, please see my attached screenshot from the Android emulator.

Is it possible to do this so that the content appears under the camera as well?

[screenshot showing content partly hiden under camera on Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUIMj.jpg)

TIA.

I've been following/watched a YouTube tutorial, that advertised the current solution for Android being under the status bar but the camera is still an issue here.
Also tried researching and posted in other forums.